# Difference between C-x m and M-x mail

Tags: email, smtpmail, attachment

When I attach files using `M-x mml-attach-file`,

`C-x m` does attachments as expected but

`M-x mail` just sends the text

```
<#part type="text/plain" filename="~/Downloads/coding_style.c" disposition=attachment description="modified coding_style.c"> <#/part>
```

Why are these different when sending mail works with both?

Answer (score 5):

I know nothing about mail in Emacs, but running `C-h k C-x m` tells me that `C-x m` runs the command `compose-mail`, which is different from `mail`. This is presumably why they behave differently. You can find out more with `C-h f compose-mail` and `C-h f mail`.

Answer (score 0):

`C-x m` calls `compose-mail` but not `mail`.  According to documentation `compose-mail`:

> Start composing a mail message to send.
>   This uses the user's chosen mail composition package
>   as selected with the variable `mail-user-agent'.

for `mail-user-agent`:

> Your preference for a mail composition package.

but `mail` from `sendmail.el`:

> Edit a message to be sent.

So, if set, `compose-mail` could call `mail` from `sendmail.el` for creating and sending email.